# codeigniter website on a host- CSS changes does not change front end elements

Tags: css, codeigniter, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, host

- My site is in a Host. (Not localhost)
- Framework: CodeIgniter.
- Changes made using CSS: Flot chart's legend

I did changes to front end using Chrome tools/developer tools.
I can see all the changes I made instantly.

I FTP to the site, downloaded the CSS file, did necessary changes (same as chrome developer changers) and uploaded the CCS file.

I access the site, but I cannot see the changes I made using CSS file.

Comment: can you give a link of your site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if your hosted CSS contains the latest changes
2. If CSS is ok try to open chrome dev tools and inspect the element that you are trying to modify. Scroll through the CSS applied to that element and check if your styles are there.
3. If you didn't find any of the styles that you are tring to apply to the element probably you misspelled the selector name. Remember to check .class #id

also, in order to ensure that your CSS files are not cached suffix your php files like this

```
<link href="/stylesheet.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /&glt;
```

**EDIT**
tip above also works for any resource! (css, javascript files, images ...)

Comment: thats a cool tip adding the time to the css link while doing development.

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+F5. It's hard refresh

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did command+shift+R on my MacBook Pro. Sorry it does not work. I appreciate your help

Comment: Please give me a link and show me where you changed in css and where is it in html (from view source, give me what lines what elements)

Answer (score 0):

change the name of the css file so there are no cache issues and then check. if that does not work then look at your source code and copy paste the address of the css file to make absolutely certain you have the link correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSS is still cached so have a Look at this popular question: [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

There are some solutions how you can force your browser to refresh the CSS or js.

The easiest answer you will get is using something like this:

```
  /styles/screen.css?v=1234
```

If you did a change all you have to do is to +1 the counter!

In PHP you van also use this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css?v=<?php echo filemtime('mycss.css') ?>"/>
```

It's like an autocounter using the timestamp of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

In the DevTools Settings (<kbd>F1</kbd>) or in the `Network` panel (depends on what version of Chrome you are using) tick the `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` checkbox. If caching is your problem, it should get fixed.